# Ensuring constness of member variable of const pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, compiler-errors, constants

Why do this code compile smoothly?

```
class myvector
{
public:
    myvector()
    {
        begin = new double[10];
        end = begin+10;
    }
    ~myvector()
    {
        delete[] begin;
    }

    double *begin;
    double *end;
};

class VectorWorker
{
public:
    VectorWorker(){}
    void doWork(const myvector *v)
    {
        for (int i=0;i<10;i++)
            v->begin[i] = i; // I don't want this to compile! I'd prefer compiler says me I can't modify v->begin
    }

    void doWork2(const myvector *const v) const
    {
        for (int i=0;i<10;i++)
            v->begin[i] = i; // I don't want this to compile!  I'd prefer compiler says me I can't modify v->begin
    }

    void doWork3(const myvector &v)
    {
        for (int i=0;i<10;i++)
            v.begin[i] = i; // I don't want this to compile!  I'd prefer compiler says me I can't modify v->begin
    }
};

int main(int, char*[])
{

    myvector x;
    VectorWorker work;
    work.doWork(&x);

    work.doWork2(&x);
    work.doWork3(x);

    return 0;
}
```

I'd expect that passing `const myvector *v` to `VectorWorker::doWork` method, should ensure me that variables in `myvector` are left intact, but actually they are modified. How can I be sure that read-only operations are allowed to `doWork` method?

Actually I can't modify `double *begin` and `double *end` variables to be `const double *` because they are from a third-party library. But how can I be sure that they are left intact when passed through an instance of the class they belong to, even if through `const pointer`?

The code is available in coliru: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bb43fbebebdb5872

Comment: Modifying `v.begin` and modifying what `v.begin` points to are rather different things. The usual solution is to expose only a non-modifying interface if the object is `const`, but if you have no control over the definition of `myvector` there isn't much you can do.

Comment: [OT]: You don't respect rule of 5 for `myvector`.

Answer (score 2):

Use accessors:

```
class myvector
{
public:
    //previous code

    const double* get_begin() const { return begin; }
    const double* get_end() const { return end; }
    double* get_begin() { return begin; }
    double* get_end() { return begin; }
private:
    double *begin;
    double *end;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

So you can't do it with a double ptr. If you really want it to 'just work' then you could create a custom DoublePtr type:

```
class DoublePtr
{
public:
    DoublePtr() { _ptr = 0; }
    DoublePtr(double* ptr) { _ptr = ptr; }
    //index operators provide lookups
    double& operator[](int pos) {
        return _ptr[pos];
    }
    const double& operator[](int pos) const {
        return _ptr[pos];
    }

    //casts for backward compatibility
    operator double*() {
        return _ptr;
    }
    operator const double*() const {
        return _ptr;
    }
private:
    double* _ptr;
};

class myvector
{
public:
    myvector()
    {
        buffer = new double[10];
        begin = DoublePtr(buffer);
        end = DoublePtr(buffer+10);
    }
    ~myvector()
    {
        delete[] begin;
    }

    DoublePtr begin;
    DoublePtr end;
private:
    double* buffer;
};
```

Then the VectorWorker code will not need changing at all.

Having said all that - if you can use them, accessors do seem like a better way to go.

Answer (score 0):

const is not transitive; whilst the pointer itself will be const (you can;t set 'begin'), the value it points to is not.

So you cant get this behaviour without modifying myvector (which you say is not an option) or by only accessing it via a wrapper that only provides const access.

Its not exactly an ideal solution - it would be better to fix the myvector abomination (what library is this from?).

e.g.

```
class myvectorconst
{
private:
    myvector* vec_;
public:
    myvectorconst(myvector* vec) : vec_(vec) {}
    double const* begin() const { return vec_->begin; }
};

class VectorWorker
{
public:
    VectorWorker(){}
    void doWork(const myvectorconst& v)
    {
        for (int i=0;i<10;i++)
            v->begin()[i] = i; // Won't compile.
    }
// ...
};
```